Keyboard layout re-mapped in Windows: It works everywhere but in GUI apps on WSL2
I used powertoys to have a MacOS-style keyboard in Windows and I managed to do it. For example Shift+Alt+8 results in \ as I would expect given my keyboard (Swedish layout) in both TUI and GUI apps on Windows 10.
However, in WSL2 this only happens in the TUI. For example, if I use the mentioned shortcut on Nautilus, nothing happens or if I use it in Gvim I get a ^\. Any idea how to solve it? Or is it a bug worth issuing in WSL2 issue tracker?
I have Ubuntu 22.04.3 on WSL2 and wsl.exe --version returns:
WSL version: 2.1.5.0
Kernel version: 5.15.146.1-2
WSLg version: 1.0.60
MSRDC version: 1.2.5105
Direct3D version: 1.611.1-81528511
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.4046

